# ESP32 Dev Kit C - WS2812

Tags: esp32, ws2812b

My Components:
ESP32 Dev Kit C from Az - Delivery
Power Adapter 5V - 5A
Level Shifter
RGB - STRIP

I'm using the Adafruit_neoPixel library. My programs are working fine with the LED-Strip, but every time i clear the strip some random LEDS are lightning in different colors and with different brightness.
On my ESP8266 it worked without problems.

The assembly
https://drive.google.com/file/d/116THKp5w-OJPHqCHTN398WxaH3-hWZXn/view?usp=sharing

My Test-Code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define LED_PIN3 17
#define LED_COUNT3 150
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip3(LED_COUNT3, LED_PIN3, NEO_RGB + NEO_KHZ800);
void setup() 
{
  // Initialsierung Strip 3
  strip3.begin();
  strip3.clear();
  strip3.show();
}
void loop() 
{
  uint32_t green3 = strip3.Color(255,0,0,0);
  uint32_t blue3 = strip3.Color(0,0,255,0);
  uint32_t red3 = strip3.Color(0,255,0,0);
  
  //strip.setBrightness(25);
  //strip2.setBrightness(25);
  strip3.setBrightness(125);
  
  strip3.fill(green3, 0, 150);
  strip3.show();
  delay(5000);
  strip3.clear();
  strip3.show();
  delay(5000);
}
```

The Random LED`s:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fl7ZuFU_VvzgoixMGkxw5vANh4sGxeNN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: random LEDs with random colors/brightness sounds like grounding issue. However try FAST LED library https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED fully supported for ESP32.

Comment: What is the nature of this "level shifter"?  That sounds suspicious.  Other than that, there's very little in your posting which would hint at the problem, since you're mostly using pre-created things and not really do much engineering in realms which are either original or exposed by your question to examination.

Comment: The same program and the same assembly worked with ESP8266, but don't work with ESP32? Did you changed the board settings in the compiler?